# Check for mysql ascending field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in my mysql database called 'rank'.

I want to run a simple as possible query or php loop that checks if there's an increment starting from 1 in this field across all rows. Doesn't matter the order of the rows, just as long as there's a row with 'rank' of 1, another of 2, another of 3, etc.

I have some code to run if there's a break in the sequence so Im just looking for help on the most resource friendly way of checking.

There needs to be a row with a rank of 1 also.

Comment: you want to know if the increment start from 1 and it's continuous, right?? and if it's not continuous what should happen?

Comment: i have a bunch of code to run if it isn't, too much to post and it's not needed for the question, just say if theres a break then x=1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return a row with 0 as the missingrank if rank 1 exists, and any rows in addition to missingrank 0 are missing ranks.

```
 SELECT T.ID - 1 AS [MISSINGRANK]
 FROM URTABLE T
 LEFT JOIN URTABLE T2 ON T.rank = T2.rank + 1
 WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look to this:

```
mysql> set @a:=1;


mysql> select actor_id,if(@a<>actor_id,'break',@a),@a:=@a+1 from t2 order by actor_id;
+----------+-----------------------------+----------+
| actor_id | if(@a<>actor_id,'break',@a) | @a:=@a+1 |
+----------+-----------------------------+----------+
|        1 | 1                           |        2 |
|        2 | 2                           |        3 |
|        3 | 3                           |        4 |
|        4 | 4                           |        5 |
|        5 | 5                           |        6 |
|        6 | 6                           |        7 |
|        7 | 7                           |        8 |
.....
|       99 | 99                          |      100 |
|      101 | break                       |      101 |
|      102 | break                       |      102 |
|      103 | break                       |      103 |
|      104 | break                       |      104 |
|      105 | break                       |      105 |
+----------+-----------------------------+----------+
207 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't know if it's what you want to (I tried in local host), where breaks mean that the actor_id has broken the auto_auto_increment, you can add group by , order by, etc, whatever you need